# General form for series coefficient of Taylor series expansion of $(x+1)^{1/x}$

Tags: taylor-expansion

What is the general form for the series coefficients of Taylor expansion of $(x+1)^{1/x}$?

The first few terms are as follows:

$$e-\frac{e x}{2}+\frac{11 e x^2}{24}-\frac{7 e x^3}{16}+\frac{2447 e x^4}{5760}-\frac{959 e x^5}{2304}+\frac{238043 e x^6}{580608} -\frac{67223 e x^7}{165888}+\frac{559440199 e x^8}{1393459200}-\frac{123377159 e x^9}{309657600}+...$$

Comment: Around what point?

Comment: @mickep around zero